# Render regular HTML in IONIC

Tags: ionic-framework

Is it possible to render regular HTML code in ionic? The reason behind is i want to render a chart, that is generated by a python code (Using Altair)

Thanks.

Comment: yes, absolutely possible. embed your html code and add css to style it.

Comment: Hi Sam, sorry. Can you point me to resources on how can i do that?

Comment: Can you please show Sample Data or HTML your are generating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render regular html in ionic.
Let's assume you want to render the chart into an ion-item
The code goes something like this

```
    <ion-list>
         <ion-item>
          <!-- Some code, you may use *ngFor to display the entire data -->
          Example: <div class="exClass"><!-- May be a table -->{{ someData }}</div>
         </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```